# .search:focus I want the expanding search Box to overlap menu part not Push them w/o Jquery or Javascript

Tags: html, css, search

I have a simple search box, which is also a **bit animated** →

```
<input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search">
```

I have made the expanding search box through a Focus effect →

```
.search:focus {
    width: 225px;
    outline: none;
}
```

I also a tried a property →

```
`Position: absolute`,
```

but still it didn't gave the effect what I wanted.

What I wanted?
when I click on search box it should expand like it is expanding now, but it should overlap the menu. Currently it is pushing away the menu item.

The best way to visualize what i want is to check the search box of stackoverflow.com I want the same expanding effect →
Expanding + Overlapping over the menu not pushing.

The working Live code for browser troubleshooting [can be found here](http://html.ankishpost.com/).

Comment: https://codepen.io/CBeghin/pen/HeuiF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css,

```
.header-menu > ul {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 190px;
}
.search {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    /*margin-left: 15px;*/
    width: 175px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    /*float: right;*/
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Example of positioning element

```css
html,body,.relative_div{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

.relative_div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.relative_div>div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #888;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
}

.left-top {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.left-bottom {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.right-top {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.right-bottom {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class=relative_div>
  <div class=left-top>left-top</div>
  <div class=left-bottom>left-bottom</div>
  <div class=right-top>right-top</div>
  <div class=right-bottom>right-bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: How can I check? if possible add it to live site so I can debug

Comment: Hey there, what does this property do → right: 0 My main reason for posting was not just fixing, but learning. where were I going wrong in my approach? Do I have a knowledge gap.

Comment: It's setting element position `0` from `right` relative to it's parent element ***[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)***

Comment: But you are not using the Keyword: "position', but just "right". How come that property works? I think it is and it was all the power play of positioning an element. Isn't it?

Comment: Adding `right: 0` makes it possible to animate it's width (on focus, of course) from right to left, that's it.

Comment: Using right fixes element to the right position relative to its parent, and animation will also work with out setting `right: 0` ,if you guys need to read more about [positioning, read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: @AdiYogi I have added an example, check once

Answer (score 1):

I think wrapping the search element inside a list-item would be slightly better practice in the direction to achieve the effect.

Even though you got the quick solution to your question, still I have a small workaround for you here that I wrote in the meanwhile. It's not a big deal, just bit more better in terms of structure, with more solid markup.

What I did below:

- Wrapped the search input box inside an `li` to maintain the flow of the list
- Called it `search-wrap`, gave it a width (equal to our search-box), made it relatively-positioned so that it may carry our absolutely-positioned search box
- Absolutely-positioned the search box
- Added some styles for our search-box on `:focus`

Have a see.

```css
.header-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.search-wrap {
  width: 175px;
  position: relative;
  height: 27px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.search {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 175px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.search:focus {
  width: 225px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>

    <li class="search-wrap">
      <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

One more thing you might want to consider to improve with this particular section is that (always) consider using form input elements inside a form.

That's it. Hope it added to some value. Cheers!

Comment: Hey there can you please guide me more over this → One more thing you might want to consider to improve with this particular section is that (always) consider using form input elements inside a form.

Comment: Sure. It's okay to use form elements without forms based on the need of an interface, as mentioned in the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls). But if we talk about search elements, they are usually seen wrapped inside a `form` element (with action attributes), as they are supposed to act on form submission. So, it's more meaningful for a search box to have form to act upon something.

Comment: I implemented your solution, but it is creating some bugs. Please check.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong. If you modified the HTML and the CSS correctly, it should've worked by now.

Comment: Modified everything correctly. <li class="search-wrap"><input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>

Comment: Edited the code a bit. It should work now. Give it a go one more time.

Comment: Both people have helped me. I am confused whom should I upvote.